# How to build a jar using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to build my project with Maven. How do I do that?

- Maven is installed,
- the project is called Sertsu1
- it contains a pom.xml-file

What must be entered in the command line to start building?

Comment: Really? http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html

Comment: [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: A hint: `mvn` + goal (make sure Maven is on your path)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to create an artifact (jar-file) you need to invoke

```
mvn package
```

This is very basic and you should take your time to read the suggested manuals before using maven.

Answer (score 7):

If your project is organized as Maven expects, e.g. your source code is in the `src\main\java` directory you can run

> mvn package

to just build your jar

> mvn install

to install it in your local Maven repository

> mvn clean

to remove a previous build

Beware that you won't go very far with Maven without reading about it. You can start with this [book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html).

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the folder that contains the `pom.xml` and enter

```
mvn package
```

(for a quick result)

Your machine needs to be connected to the internet as maven will download a lot of files from public repositories.